# Slope m of least squares best fit line from two arrays

Tags: python, subroutine

Given two text files and 'x' and 'y' as arrays, write a subroutine that will give the slope 'm' and intercept 'b' of the least squares best fit line.

> x = 1,2,3,4
>
> y = 5,6,7,8
>
> m = ((sum(xy)-sum(x)ybar)/((sumx^2)-(sum(x)xbar))
>
> b = ybar - m(xbar).
>
> xbar and ybar are the mean values of the x and y arrays.

My instructor said we cannot use intrinsic python functions beyond np.loadtxt.

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to do this than besides defining the 4 array combinations, then the sums of each of the 4 combos, and then finding m.

I tried to define each sum of the array combinations as nested loops.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/Bob/Documents/School/Comp Phys/xlsf.dat")
y = np.loadtxt("C:/Users/Bob/Documents/School/Comp Phys/ylsf.dat")

xbar = np.mean(x)
ybar = np.mean(y)

nx = len(x)
ny = len(y)

q = print(xbar)

sum1=[[0 for i in range(nx)] for j in range(ny)]

for i in range (0, nx):
    for j in range (0, ny):
        sum1[i][j] = x[i] * y[j]

for i in range (ny):
        for j in range (nx):
            ((sum1[i][j]))

sum2=[[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ybar)]

for q in range (0, nx):
    for r in range (0, ybar):
        sum2[q][r] = x[q] * ybar[r]

for q in range (ybar):
    for r in range (nx):
        ((sum2[q][r]))
```

Python is getting caught up with the sum2 part, with the following error:

> sum2=[[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ybar)]
>
> > TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: The equation to calculate linear regression doesn't involve the mean of the data... https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation

Comment: The equation given in the problem specifically states that we have to use the mean values of x and y data.

Comment: ahh i see, sorry I missed that in your question.

Comment: @BobertTheBob it's usually useful to include any error messages you get from running the code.

Comment: Also, do you mean you can only use intrinsic functions? `np.loadtxt` isn't an intrinsic function...

Comment: @Enthus3d, the error for sum2 is

 sum2=[[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ybar)]

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: @BobertTheBob I'm not too familiar with your explanation of what sum1 and sum2 do, just from the code. Is it possible to explain or link it to the equations from above?

Comment: @BobertTheBob I made some assumptions on how your algorithm may work, and added some bits in an answer to help guide you through it. I believe the second for loop of each of your two sums is superfluous, as (sum1[i][j]) does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
xbar = np.mean(x)
ybar = np.mean(y)
```

In your code, xbar and ybar are means of the arrays, given as floats (numpy type float 64).

In your lines below, you use range(ybar) for your for loops.

```
sum2=[[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ybar)]

for q in range (0, nx):
    for r in range (0, ybar):
        sum2[q][r] = x[q] * ybar[r]

for q in range (ybar):
    for r in range (nx):
        ((sum2[q][r]))
```

but, your for loops cannot use non-integers to loop, because they cannot loop, for example, 4.5 times. You may need to structure your code to calculate the sums in a different way, such as using a different variable as a range to loop on.

I am still not sure exactly which calculations you are trying to do, but I've structured the following code which you can go through. It's simple and does every single step as-is, leaving you to optimize the code itself to run better, but hopefully it'll give you an idea on how to structure your calculations.

```
# sum1 array, x*y
sum1=[[0 for i in range(nx)] for j in range(ny)]
for i in range (0, nx):
    for j in range (0, ny):
        sum1[i][j] = x[i] * y[j]

# sum2 array, x
# notice that the array sum2 can just be completely replaced by x[]
sum2=[[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ny)]
for q in range (0, nx):
        sum2[q][0] = x[q] 

# sum3 array, x^2
# same for sum3, we can just replace it with x[]*x[]
sum3 = [[0 for q in range(nx)] for r in range(ny)]
for q in range (0, nx):
        sum2[q][0] = x[q]*x[q]

term1 = 0
term2 = 0
term3 = 0
term4 = 0

# sum each 'sum array' and apply them to the term variables
for i in range(nx):
    for j in range(ny):
        term1 += sum1
        term2 += sum2
        term3 += sum3
        term4 += sum2

term2 = term2 * ybar // we multiply that sum by the coefficients 
term4 = term4 * xbar

m = (term1 - term2 ) / (term3 - term4 ) // calculate m
b = ybar - m * xbar // calculate b
```

Comment: Figuring out the rest of the logic for the calculations, will post in a bit